# I keep getting 404 error not found from ajax url in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

Ajax url keeps throwing a 404 not found error even though it returns the desired response in the console under response.

I have hosted this site as a subdomain (http://example.org/codeigniter-folder/). I also have a wordpress site on the same domain (http://example.org/blog/). I have forced a redirect to (http://example.org/codeigniter-folder/) by default from the hosting company. therefore, there are two .htaccess files. one in example.org, the other in codeigniter-folder. I'm running on apache server

```
example.org
-codeigniter-folder
--application
----controllers
------Welcome.php
----views
------common
--------top.php
--------bottom.php
--------header.php
--------footer.php
------welcome_message.php
------about.php
------events.php
--system
--assets
----js
------all js scripts
```

only the folders that are of interest is what I listed above

Here's the view in welcome_message.php

```
<form name="volunteer_form" method="post" action="" class="volunter-form vol-form">

    <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
        </div>
    </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="subbtn" class="btn btn-white py-3 px-5 btnsubmit" value="Send Message">
    </div>
</form>
```

here's the bottom located in views/common/bottom.php

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4"
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/mdb/js/mdb.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/aos.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/scrollax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/google-map.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var baseurl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";</script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

I posted the bottom because i have a feeling perhaps one of these linked files may be in conflict with the ajax block i have written below

here's the JS in assets/js/custom.js

```
$("#subbtn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
    var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
    // var phone = $('input[name="phone"]').val();
    // var subject = $('input[name="subject"]').val();
    // var message = $('textarea[name="message"]').val();
    var formdata = {name:name, email:email};

    $.ajax({
      url:baseurl+"ajax",
      type:"POST",
      data:formdata,
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(){
          //console.log(response.success);
          alert(name);
      },
      error:function(){
          console.log("error");

      }

    });
    alert(name);
  });

});
```

Just so you know I have tried url:"ajax", even hardcoded the url, still did not work. with url:"ajax", i see the correct response too inthe console.
So I will go ahead to post the .htaccess i.e the one in codeigniter-folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and here's the one in example.org

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.org\/site" [R=301,L]
```

The last alert() works. that means my js works except for the ajax block. When executed, the error function always gets executed

this is my controller in Ajax.php

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();


    }

  public function index()
  {
    $response['success'] = $this->input->post('name').' '.$this->input->post('email');
    echo json_encode($response);
  }
}
```

What am I missing? what do i do to have ajax interpret the url correctly? thank you.

Comment: custom.js will not be able to read this php line `url:"<?php echo base_url('ajax'); ?>",`

Comment: sorry I forgot to add that I have declared a baseurl variable in the body of welcome_message.php to get the base_url(). it still id not work

Comment: `.js` file can't execute php code you need to manually right path to the controller file

Comment: i already did here ```var baseurl = "<?php echo basse_url(); ?>"``` in ```views/common/bottom.php```

Comment: i discovered my problem has to do with .htaccess configuration. i pointed example.org to example.org/codigniter-folder. how can i properly define the .htaccess rule to see my ajax url?

Comment: try outputting your ajax url in your javascript code like alert(baseurl+"ajax"); or console.log(baseurl+"ajax"); A good place for it can be after e.preventDefault(); line inside button's click event function